# SQL results to get email thread

Tags: sql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have a message system table.  It stores the typical from, to, and even about (3-way system) and the RepliedToID...the ID of the message that this one may be a reply to.  Each message can have several replies.  It can eventually create a thread of messages chained together.

I'm stumped as to how I can create a query that can take any message in the thread with the ID and retrieve messages before and after on the thread.

```
=============
MID   ReplyID   Message
1               First Message
2     1         Second Mess replied to #1
3     2         Third Mess replied to #2
4     2         Fourth Mess replied to #2
5     4         Fifth Mess replied to #4
=============
```

If I had any single MID in this, is there a way to get the results for all messages in the thread?  (of Course, there will be all kinds of messages mixed in between these as the MID is an autonumber key)

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: Please add a simple SQL script to create the table/data locally.

Comment: Do you want the entire table returned like this, or just a particular message chain?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: This can't be done with "regular" SQL. You need recursive queries and each DB does this differrently. Some don't support it at all and then you can only issue query after query, following the thread manually. Please specify which DB you are using.

Comment: I want just a single chain.  I don't know exactly what DBMS it is as it is behind a rapid development platform running on the AWS (Caspio).  I was thinking that this might not be possible through a query without a dangerous loop, but I don't have server side scripting options...only JS...which would cause far too much data usage.  Trying to avoid creating another whole table just to create and maintain the association of messages to one another when each message is only the reply to a single message, but a chain exists I need to see more easily. Ugghhh!!!

Answer (score 0):

Using the following table and data :

```
MID ReplyId Message       
1   0   First Message                       f
2   1   Second Mess replied to #1
3   2   Third Mess replied to #2
4   2   Fourth Mess replied to #2
5   4   Fifth Mess replied to #4
6   0   New thread
7   6   Reply to new thread
8   4   Reply to #4
```

If you use a SQL Statement similar to this :

```
SELECT t1.MID, t1.Message, t2.ReplyID, t2.Message as Msg_Reply 
FROM test_table t1
CROSS JOIN test_table t2 ON t1.MID = t2.ReplyID
ORDER BY ReplyID
```

It gives you back a table like this

```
MID Message                 ReplyID Msg_Reply
1   First Message               1   Second Mess replied to #1
2   Second Mess replied to #1   2   Third Mess replied to #2
2   Second Mess replied to #1   2   Fourth Mess replied to #2
4   Fourth Mess replied to #2   4   Fifth Mess replied to #4
4   Fourth Mess replied to #2   4   Reply to 4
6   New thread                  6   Reply to new thread
```

I guess after that you could just loop through these data and display it following the thread.